# Scenario of extending Thread class and implementing Runnable interface

Tags: java, multithreading, runnable

I am new to thread programming in Java and hence this basic question. (I checked, but could not find this question previously asked)

I read that threads can be created either by inheriting the Thread class or by implementing the Runnable interface.
I saw a code which had both to the same class.

```
public class ThreadExample extends Thread implements Runnable {
}
```

I was wondering what kind of situation would want this and if there is any advantage to this, what is it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

extending `Thread` *and* implementing `Runnable` is useless (`Thread` already implements `Runnable`).  You pretty much *always* want to implement `Runnable` (and *not* extend `Thread`).  That gives you the flexibility of using a `Thread` directly (not recommended) or using one of the newer `ThreadPool` implementations in `java.util.concurrent` (recommended).

Answer (score 5):

No, There is no advantage of using this approach, because, Thread class implements Runnable interface. So, if your class extends Thread class. It means, it's also implementing Runnable interface.

[image: http://www.developerfusion.com/pix/articleimages/may05/javathread3.jpg]

Answer (score 4):

IN this specific situation it's not very useful, as other posters have explained it's fairly obvious that `Thread` already implements `Runnable`.

In *some* cases, "stating the obvious" can be useful though, just as a "reminder" to the user of your class: if you have a fairly large hierarchy of super-classes and interfaces, with several levels of inheritance (some of them in 3rd-party libraries), it could be useful as a helper to declare a class as implementing a specific interface, even though it implements it *by definition* because its superclass already implements it or implements one of the sub-class of that interface.

It's specially useful with **marker interfaces** (some people might object they should not be used at all, and they are bad practices - well sometimes you don't control the environment fully), i.e. interfaces with no actual implementation and just designed to mark your object eligible for a special function (e.g. `Cloneable`). In such a case, marking each of the allowed classes even though their parents are already eligible can be more explicit, so more useful.

Answer (score -1):

Runnable interface means assigning one job to many threads
while Thread class,each of threads has a unique object associated with it.

Comment: this is in no way even remotely correct

Comment: Please read [How do I write a good answer?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) before attempting to answer more questions.

Answer (score -1):

Implementing runnable interface would be preferable when you need needs more flexibility of extending other base classes.

Comment: Please read [How do I write a good answer?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) before attempting to answer more questions.

Comment: I already read that. Please tell me - What is the wrong in my answer?